# Removing Gibbs Phenomenon

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I am working with a sample of 20 points given from an unknown 1-periodic function that are plotted like this: [Original sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIEiF.png)

I am using Inverse Fast Fourier Transform (ifft) to recover the signal resampled in 1000 points at [0,1) that is plotted like this: [Resampled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3qBK.png)

It is showing a Gibbs Phenomenon at the end of the signal. What can be causing this fact? As far as I know Gibbs Phenomenon occurs near a jump discontinuity...

Any idea about why is this happening and how could I solve it?

Comment: Wilbraham phenomenon discovered in 1848, and rediscovered by Gibbs 50 years later, is a fact... it cannot be wished away. That is, the finite partial sums of Fourier series of a function behave badly at discontinuities. Bang. But/and the Fejer-kernel version, for example, as an instance of Cesaro summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Fourier cosine series.  This amounts to extending the function to be even on $[-1,1]$ and then making it periodic with period $2$.  That function will be continuous.

Comment: Thanks. I have extended my initial sample from `[0, 0.006, 0.024, ...., 0.94, 0.97, 0.99]` to `[0.99, 0.97, 0.94, ..., 0.024, 0.006, 0, 0.006, 0.024, ..., 0.94,0.97, 0.99]` is that correct?

Comment: You don't have to do anything to your sample.  The Fourier cosine series of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is $$\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(k\pi x)$$ where $$a_k =2 \int_0^1 f(x) \cos(k\pi x)\; dx$$

Comment: ... but if you already have everything set up for IFFT you might as well do it that way (taking the interval as $[-1,1]$).

Comment: Okay. So I extended the sample on left-side by a reverse copy of itself and thanks to this, we eliminated the jump so now I have a continous signal in [-1,1].

Answer (score 1):

If you makes the function periodic by pasting copies of it side by side, contiguously, then you will have a jump continuity at each integer.

There's nothing to do about it unless you change from Fourier transform to something else or modify the function to have a smooth step.

Comment: So you mean, that if I take a larger initial sample (i.e. 40 points instead of 20), perhaps it could improve?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. You cannot avoid Gibbs phenomenon. As soon as there is a jump discontinuity it will be there.

Comment: Then how should i make my function to have a smooth step from my initial vector of samples?

Comment: Robert Israel has a good idea that I forgot.